# Open Third Modal using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I'm trying to open a third modal from a form. I have a button to open one modal, then a next button which opens up a second modal, but looking to have a next-button that then opens a third modal.

This is the script I'm using to open the second modal:

```php
<!-- trigger second modal -->
<?php if(!empty($_GET)){ ?>
    <script>
        $('#enterTeamModal').modal();
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
```

The third modal has the ID `id="uploadModal"` if I change it like this:

```php
<!-- trigger second modal -->
<?php if(!empty($_GET)){ ?>
    <script>
        $('#uploadModal').modal();
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
```

It opens both the second modal and third modal at the same time.

Comment: Not enough known here without a [mcve]

Comment: You have same `if(!empty($_GET)){` and if `$_GET` is not empty then both modals will show. Try to be more specific than just `$_GET` and check for a specific key in `$_GET`